# Backup no Postgres

Tags: postgresql, backup, administração-postgresql

O postgres tem alguma tabela de sistema que se possa fazer select para descobrir quando foi feito o último backup tal como seu status(se rodou normal ou deu erro) ?

Ou seja, como retirar o máximo de informações de backup no postgres ?

***EDITADO***

Eu estou pegando a data do backup do arquivo gerado pelo `pg_basebackup` que fica na pasta de pg_xlog ( uso Linux). Nessa pasta ele cria um arquivo `.backup` após o término do processo.

O arquivo é assim :

```
TART WAL LOCATION: 4/42000028 (file 000000010000000400000042)
STOP WAL LOCATION: 4/42000130 (file 000000010000000400000042)
CHECKPOINT LOCATION: 4/42000060
BACKUP METHOD: streamed
BACKUP FROM: master
START TIME: 2019-02-26 13:30:01 BRT
LABEL: pg_basebackup base backup
STOP TIME: 2019-02-26 13:30:19 BRT
```

Notei em que um outro backup em vez do `BRT` tinha `-O3`. O que esse `BRT` significa ?

POde o pg_basekacup gerar esse arquivo mesmo dando algum tipo de erro no backup?

Comment: Existem diversas maneiras de se fazer back-up no PostgreSQL e apenas a replicação, que pode ser encarada como uma forma de back-up, tem registro no catálogo do sistema. Mas não parece ser o que está procurando.

Comment: Como você faz o backup? É Servidor Windows ou Linux?

Comment: Servidor Linux. Fiz com pg_basebackup.

Comment: E como você trata os segmentos WAL?

Comment: Talvez você esteja utilizando uma estratégia errada de backup.

Comment: Apenas para efeito de teste, você já tentou restaurar seu BD a partir de um destes "backups"? Entendo que você não trata os segmentos de WAL junto com o pg_basebackup.

Answer (score 2):

Não existe nenhuma tabela ou view nativa no PostgreSQL para esta finalidade, mas o que pode ser feito é uma solução manual da seguinte forma:

Tanto o `pg_dump.exe` (responsável pelo backup), quanto o `pg_restore.exe` (responsável pela restauração) podem receber parâmetros. Você pode fazer um backup salvando as informações em um arquivo `.txt` e posteriormente salvar estas em uma tabela através do comando `COPY FROM FILE`. Exemplo abaixo.

```
create table test_bkp (
    id integer
);

INSERT INTO test_bkp (id) SELECT g.id
FROM generate_series(1, 10000) AS g (id) ;

--COMANDO DE BACKUP
pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -Fc -v -t test_bkp -f D:\test_bkp\test_bkp.backup postgres 2> D:\test_bkp\test_bkp.log

--IMPORTANDO INFORMAÇÕES DO BACKUP
create table test_log (
    conteudo text
);

COPY test_log (conteudo) FROM 'D:\\test_bkp\\test_bkp.log'  encoding 'windows-1251';
```

Outra alternativa é executar o backup através de SQL com o comando `COPY FROM PROGRAM` (só é possível com usuários com certos privilégios) e rodar o comando do `pg_dump` direto, porém é mais suscetível a erros na minha opinião. Esse é um exemplo simples, pesquise mais sobre os parâmetros do `pg_dump` e `pg_restore` e sobre o comando `COPY`.